# show message when like button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following code to alert the user when he click the facebook like button. It is alerting the user only on Opera browser. How do I fix this problem and make it work with all browsers ?

```
<script>
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
    function(response) {
        alert("You liked the URL");
    }
);
</script>
```

I can also use Jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where did you put this code ?

For me you have to put this in the init like this :

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId  : APP_ID,
      status : true, 
      cookie : true, 
      xfbml  : true 
    });

    FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
        function(response) {
            alert("You liked the URL");
        }
    );    
};
```

If you have already call the FB.init, you have to use a trick like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function hasFBLoad(){
        if(FB != 'undefined'){
            FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
                function(response) {
                    alert("You liked the URL");
                }
            );
        }else{
            setTimeout('hasFBLoad()', 200);
        }
    }
    hasFBLoad();
</script>
```

Comment: I don't understand your comment. If you already use the FB.init, you have to use a trick, i will edit my post.

Comment: Still the same problem. Does it matter if I load the script after or before the like button 
?

Comment: For me it doesn't, but Facebook recommend to put all the stuff directly after the `<body>` tag. I've  just tried my solution and it worked well for me on Firefox and Chrome ... (the 1st solution)